# How to update data in the child component by click event in the parent component

Tags: reactjs

I´m new to reactjs. I have a parent component with a list of buttons and child component with a map. With a click on the button i want to pass coordinates to the child component, but i´m stuck in my attempt to update the data inside the map component.

The parent component with the button click event updating the state and passing that state to the Map component.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(data){
        this.setState({data: data});
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        {list.map( data => (
                            <li key={}>
                                <button                                 
                                    type="button" 
                                    onClick={() => this.handleClick(data)} >
                                </button>
                            </li>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <Map data={this.state.data} />
                </div>    
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The child map component with the function MapComponent that will not get the data from the updated state.

```
class Map extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            data: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({data: this.props.data});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <MapContainer zoom={6}>
                <MapComponent data={this.state.data} />
            </MapContainer>
        );
    }
}

function MapComponent(data) {
    console.log(data);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You can change the componentDidMount to componentDidUpdate and then check if the state has changed.

Comment: My question to you is why do you need to maintain the same state in the parent (Parent) as well as in the child component (Map)?

The `Map` component can become stateless and will always have the latest value of `data` when the `Parent` re-renders [like in this case, due to the state change that is triggered by the button's on-click handler i.e.`handleClick`].

Answer (score 0):

Because you set your data once and you must set again

use this method in your Map class

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState(nextProps);
}
```